# Why can't I compare two Texture2D's?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use an accessor, as it seems to me that that is the only way to accomplish what I want to do. Here is my code:

Game1.cs

```
public class GroundTexture
{
    private Texture2D dirt;
    public Texture2D Dirt
    {
        get
        {
            return dirt;
        }

        set
        {
            dirt = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Main : Game
{
    public static Texture2D texture = tile.Texture;
    GroundTexture groundTexture = new GroundTexture();
    public static Texture2D dirt;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        Tile tile = (Tile)currentLevel.GetTile(20, 20);

        dirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Dirt");
        groundTexture.Dirt = dirt;

        Texture2D texture = tile.Texture;
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (texture == groundTexture.Dirt)
        {
            player.TileCollision(groundBounds);
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

}

I removed irrelevant information from the LoadContent and Update functions.

On the following line:

```
if (texture == groundTexture.Dirt)
```

I am getting the error

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D' and 'Game1.GroundTexture'
```

Am I using the accessor correctly? And why do I get this error? "Dirt" is Texture2D, so they should be comparable.

This using a few functions from a program called Realm Factory, which is a tile editor. The numbers "20, 20" are just a sample of the level I made below:

[image]

tile.Texture returns the sprite, which here is the content item Dirt.png

Comment: All I can say so far, is that I tried this and I could compare Texture2D references just fine. I really can't see why `groundTexture.Dirt` would be treated as a GroundTexture in your example..

Comment: Have you tried this in an empty project in order to isolate where the problem might be?

Comment: If `groundTexture.Dirt` is indeed a `Texture2D`, why not cast it to `Texture2D` and then comparing them?

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm understanding you want to check what Tile you're trying to walk over. You shouldn't check textures. You should compare tile ID. In the end the Texture is just a visual presentation of the tile context ( in this case "dirt" ).

Like so:

```
//Somewhere you see fit
enum TileType{None, Wall, Water, Dirt, Grass};

//When comparing it:
if(tile.ID == TileType.Dirt) // Do something
```

ID in this case is an enum-type of TileType. So when you load you're level you simply assign the type to the tile:

```
Tile myTile = new Tile();
mytile.ID = TileType.Dirt;
```

---

But have you tried it like

```
Texture2D dirt = groundTexture.Dirt;
if (texture == dirt)
```

But again if you want to know the context of your tiles I recommand using Enums or something similar.

It's also easier if you reference to one texture file at all time instead of creating new Dirt textures. Comparing 2 different references will result as false. I'm not sure how the Contentloader from XNA handles this but i'm just sharing just in case.

Comment: I would like to add to this answer that it is a good idea to separate the physical properties of a tile from the visual properties, because when you expand your game, you will surely have a lot of tiles which use different textures but behave identically. When you keep implementing logic based on the visual appearance, adding a new textures which doesn't do anything new will require changes all over your sourcecode, and you will have constructs like `if (texture == Dirt1 || texture == Dirt2 || texture = Wall || texture = StoneWall ...)` instead of just a simple `if (physics == SOLID)`.

Comment: @Philipp, +1. Exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cleaning and Rebuilding? Cause Like David said, I can't see any problems either.

If that doesn't help I would also see if the type does in fact return a Texture2D by print it out.

hope that helps